# JavaScript - How to scroll the li elements from top to down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have written a script which automatically allows to scroll the `li` elements from bottom to top. Here is my [script](http://jsbin.com/ahokof/16/) on jsbin.

I am trying to achieve an opposite effect of now scrolling the items from top to bottom, but haven't been successful so far. [Here](http://jsbin.com/ahokof/17) is what I have tried so far.

Can anybody help me in this regards? Thanks in advance.

---

The JavaScript code:

```
$('#scroller').bind('touchmove',function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      // Write code to scroll the items
      alert("Touch move occured");

});


function run() {
  /*  
    var prev = $("#scroller li:first-child");
    $.unique(prev).each(function(i) {
      $(this).delay(i*10).slideDown(function() {
        $(this).appendTo(this.parentNode).slideDown();
      });
    });
  */
  $("#scroller li:last").slideUp(function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $("#scroller").prepend($(this));
        $(this).slideDown();
    });
}

window.setInterval(run, 100);
```

The relevant HTML:

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="panels">
            <div  id="scroller">
                <ul>
                                      <li> Barley Wine </li>
                                      <li> Bitter Ale </li>
                                      <li> Brown Ale </li>
                                      <li> India Pale Ale </li>
                                      <li> Pale Ale </li>
                                      <li>list 1</li> 
                                      <li>list 2</li>
                                      <li>list 3</li>
                                      <li>list 4</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I added the code - it's always helpful to have appropriate, relevant code right here in your SO question in addition to a jsbin/jsfiddle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're prepending the `<li>` elements to the `<div>` instead of the `<ul>`.  Just move the "scroller" id to the `<ul>` and it gets a lot better.

Comment: Thanks for point that. It works better except for the scrolling speed. Here are my two scripts for comparing the speed of scrolling: http://jsbin.com/ahokof/18/edit and http://jsbin.com/ahokof/19/edit Any idea what could be wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: They're different, but then the code is quite different. I don't really understand what it is you're trying to do, or which one is better.

Comment: My basic aim is to scroll the items automatically. So far, the scrolling happens in the current case, but its not as smooth as the previous one (bottom -> top). The code is also different in both cases; I tried to replicate the previous code to achieve the new effect, but end-up with the current version. Can you tell me what should I modify to achieve exactly the same effect?

Comment: Well why not make the top-to-bottom code do exactly the same thing as the bottom-to-top code, except backwards?  In other words, remove the first element and append it at the end of the `<ul>`?

Comment: ah.. thats what I tried, and was not able to achieve the effect ;-)

Comment: Well maybe that attempt had the same problem (with appending to the `<div>` instead of the `<ul>`) ...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5756/discussion-between-mahi-and-pointy)